# is it possible to do low-level pixel inspection with selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, coded-ui-tests, selenium-webdriver, gui-testing

is it possible to inspect the value of a specific pixel in the browser rendered page with Selenium? can i get a buffer of the rendered page as an image?

Also, is it possible to send mouse-scroll-down commands to the browser?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a screenshot of the entire page and then manipulate the image file